# Who defines %cd% for my batch?

Tags: windows, scripting, batch-file

The following batch script prints out my current working directory.

```
echo %cd%
```

But I didn't define the **cd** variable. So who does this? Is there anything else like this?

I also checked the Environment Variables, there's none with the name of **cd**. So is this built into the **cmd.exe**?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

see `HELP SET` ...

> If Command Extensions are enabled,
>   then there are several dynamic
>   environment variables that can be
>   expanded but which don't show up in
>   the list of variables displayed by
>   SET.  These variable values are
>   computed dynamically each time the
>   value of the variable is expanded. If
>   the user explicitly defines a variable
>   with one of these names, then that
>   definition will override the dynamic
>   one described below:
>
> %CD% - expands to the current
>   directory string.
>
> %DATE% - expands to current date using
>   same format as DATE command.
>
> %TIME% - expands to current time using
>   same format as TIME command.
>
> %RANDOM% - expands to a random decimal
>   number between 0 and 32767.
>
> %ERRORLEVEL% - expands to the current
>   ERRORLEVEL value
>
> %CMDEXTVERSION% - expands to the
>   current Command Processor Extensions
>       version number.
>
> %CMDCMDLINE% - expands to the original
>   command line that invoked the
>       Command Processor.

Answer (score 2):

Run `SET /?` and in the end you'll find the answer and some other vars like that as well.

The value is stored by the command shell, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

[It's a built-in behavior of the batch processor](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/09/26/8965755.aspx), and has the same basic behavior as `ERRORLEVEL`.